# How to efficiently process strings in Java

Tags: java

I am facing some optimization problem in java. I have to process a table which has 5 attributes. The table contains about 5 millions records. To simplify the problem, let say I have to read every record one by one. Then I have to process each record. From each record I have to generate a mathematical lattice structure which has 500 nodes. In other words each record generate 500 more new records which can be referred as parents of the original record. So in total there are 500 X 5 Millions records including original plus parent records. Now the job is to find the number of distinct records out of all 500 X 5 Millions records with their frequencies. Currently I have solved this problem as follow. I convert every record to a string with value of each attribute separated by "-". And I count them in a java HashMap. Since these records involve intermediate processing. A record is converted to a string and then back to a record during intermediate steps. The code is tested and it is working fine and produce accurate results for small number of records but it can not process 500 X 5 Millions records. 
For large number of records it produce the following error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

I understand that the number of distinct records are not more than 50 thousands for sure. Which means that the data should not cause memory or heap overflow. Can any one suggest any option. I will be very thankful.

Comment: why dont you paste your code for us to take a look at possible improvements

Comment: What does a memory profiler tell you?

Comment: I can't understand your description, but I suspect you're somehow keeping all 2.5 billion records in heap, and that's not gonna fly.

Comment: Check this blog: http://kotek.net/blog/3G_map

Comment: Often, a faster solution is a *two stage* implementation: first, you find out *candidates* which could be distinct (with a help, say, of *minihash*) and only then check if they in fact are (with a lattice 500 points) distinct.

Comment: Instead of working on all records, try solving the problem in and increasingly number of records. Lets say first select top 1000 records, then 2k, 4k, 8k ... and so on. Check if your actual solution is scalable and as said above, maybe you have a ram problem.

Comment: You are right there are totally 2.5 Billions records but majority of them are similar. So if you count the number of distinct records They are less than 50 thousands. Which means the size of HashMap will never exceed 50 thousand. Which i believe is reasonable.

Comment: why don't you use a DB to store your records, then it will be a matter of simple `select` statement? Also there is no point in converting them to strings, just implement `hashcode` and `equals` and use the records themselves as keys in the map

Comment: It is fairly easy to accidentally keep a "history" of the data you process, in some sort of hashtable or linked list or some such.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you have some data-structure somewhere which is keeping references to the processed records, also known as a "memory leak".  It sounds like you intend to process each record in turn and then throw away all the intermediate data, but in fact the intermediate data is being kept around.  the garbage collector can't throw away this data if you have some collection or something still pointing to it.

Note also that there is the very important java runtime parameter "-Xmx". Without any further detail than what you've provided, I would have thought that 50,000 records would fit easily into the default values, but maybe not.  Try doubling -Xmx (hopefully your computer has enough RAM). If this solves the problem then great. If it just gets you twice as far before it fails, then you know it's an algorithm problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I am facing. i-e I am throwing away the intermediate data but some how it is kept or some week reference exist which I can't figure out where those references are.

Answer (score 0):

Using a sqlite database can used to safe (1.3tb?) data. With query´s you can find fast info back. Also the data get saved when youre program ends.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to adopt a different approach to calculating the frequencies of occurrence.  Brute force is great when you only have a few million :)

For instance, after your calculation of the 'lattice structure' you could combine that with the original data and take either the MD5 or SHA1.  This should be unique except when the data is not "distinct".  Which then should reduce your total data down back below 5 million.